# Remove 'home' folder from home page url

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have a url like this www.example.com/home/ and I cannot get rid of the home folder from the URL. The best I can do results in which causes the page to crash.

I've been working with the htaccess file and tried numerous variations. Seems like it should be a simple fix but I'm having no luck.

I'm open to non-htaccess based solutions.

You can view a copy of the htaccess at http://www.spikewebdesign.com.au/htaccess-example.html

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you have an ExpressionEngine install in a sub-folder to your web root? Or is EE in a web root, but you can't get the .htaccess file to properly remove `index.php`? Can you post your .htaccess file... I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is...

Comment: The install is in the web root. I have edited my post to include the htaccess code most of which I didn't write. The main goals were:

- ensure the website always redirect to www
- when the above redirect occurs, remove the /index.php?/ which appears in the query string
- remove /home/ when it appears in the home page URL

Comment: I'm not seeing your htaccess code in your question... could you make sure you saved the edit?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason stack exhange is throwing an error when I add it. Says I don't have enough points to put in links despite no links being added. I've added a link to the code? This is not the website using the code though.

Comment: It might be easier if you either change the file to a .txt extension or add `<pre><code>` around your content so it retains lines and wrapping. Having said that have you gone to Design > Template Manager > Home > Edit Group and checked "Make the index template in this group your site's home page?" This will make the index template the site homepage.

Answer (score 1):

OOOOk... so did you try setting a default template group? If you set your default template group to "Home", the index template in their will be resolved at 
`www.example.com` as well as `www.example.com/home`.

Comment: The default template group can be left out, yes. You can even access templates in that group, so www.example.com/foo would really load www.example.com/home/foo (provided that you did remove index.php from the URL).